# How can I use I/O redirection to run line by line commands from input files in BASH?

Tags: bash, file-io, io, file-descriptor

My professor gave me this confusing assignment :

> write a program/script which asks the user for a filename to get input
>   from, a filename to send errors and a filename to write output if the
>   filename for output and errors are the same, use the proper redirects
>
> input file will have instructions for your program such as: CHANGE: 
>   this command will tell your program to change the redirects like this:
>   CHANGE STDIN newfilename CHANGE STOUT newoutfile CHANGE STDERR
>   newerorfile STOP: stop the program and exit STOP
>
> any other input should be written to the output file Write the number
>   of lines copied to standard error
>
> your error file might look like this:

1

2

ERROR: Input file not found

filename

CHANGE: redirecting output to filename

3

4

CHANGE: redirecting errors to

> **at this point the new error file would start with

5

5

6

STOP requested

**

> here are some sample files:
>
> *> fileio.test.1*

- line 1 of first input file
- line 2 of first inputt file
- CHANGE STDIN stdin.1
- since input has changed this line should never
- get read EXIT

> 

*> stdin.1*

- line 1 of stdin.1
- line 2 of stdin.1
- CHANGE STDERR stderr.1
- line 3 of stdin.1
- CHANGE STDOUT stdout.1
- line 4 of stdin.1
- CHANGE STDOUT stdout.2
- line 5 of stdin.1
- CHANGE STDIN stdin.2
- since input has  changed this line should never get read EXIT

> *> stdin.2*

- this should go wherever it's supposed to
- EXIT
- this line shouldn't be read since our program should have exited by
  now

**However**, I am not quite sure how to interpret these directions. As a stab in the dark, I've done:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Provide filename to receive input from: " input
read -p "Provide filename to send errors to: " errorFile
read -p "Provide filename to write output to: " writeFile
#set -x
if [ -z $input ]; then
  echo "Input file needed."
  exit=1
elif [ -z $errorFile ] || [ -z $writeFile ]; then
  echo "Supply the correct number of filenames."
  exit=1
elif [ $errorFile == $writeFile ]; then
  exec 2> $errorFile
  exec >&2
else
 exec 2> $errorFile
 exec 1> $writeFile
fi

while read -r line
do
        eval $(echo "$line")
done< $input
```

**Edit**: For a function to interpret the input, I was thinking I could match for the specific commands in the testfiles and then trigger the corresponding bash command. Anything that doesn't match would be echo'd and directed to its appropriate file.

```
ChangeFD () {
 if [[ "CHANGE STDE" == ${line:0:11} ]]; then
       exec  $(echo "2>${line:14}")
elif [[ "CHANGE STDO" == ${line:0:11} ]]; then
   exec  $(echo "1>${line:14}")
elif [[ "CHANGE STDI" == ${line:0:11} ]]; then
   exec  $(echo "0<${line:13}")
else
   echo $1
fi
}
```

Comment: I'd say your professor expects you to interpret the "instructions" in the input. They are certainly not shell commands, so asking the shell to `eval` them is asking for trouble.

Comment: Ah, so I think he wants us to write functions to interpret the input.

Answer (score 1):

to count the number of lines (and output that count at regular intervals) you will need to create another variable.

Before your while loop

```
count=0
```

and within the while loop (probably just before the 'done < $input' line)

```
# increment the counter
count=$(( count + 1 ))
# output the counter var to stderr (wherever it is pointing)
echo $count >>&2
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    exec  $(echo "0<${line:13}")
> ```

This doesn't work, because redirection operators are not recognized in the replacement of `$(…)`; just use

```
   exec <${line:13}
```

instead.